# Query Table by select Distinct items given a datestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to write a query that selects distinct `uid`'s but I want to choose those distinct `uid`'s given an order on a `modified_at` column.

Example:

```
Table_A

uid  data_value modified_at
===  ========== ===========
 1       a          1/1/2016
 1       b          1/2/2016
 1       c          1/3/2016
 2       d          1/1/2016
 2       e          1/2/2016
 3       f          3/1/2016
 3       g          3/3/2016
 3       h          3/4/2016
 4       i          2/1/2016
 5       j          1/5/2016
 5       k          1/6/2016
```

So I want to select distinct uid's that have been modified most recently.

I'm not sure if there's a quick query that would allow be to do this rather than pull the information separately into a script and modify.

Write now, all I can do is

```
select distinct uid, data_value, modified_at 
from Table_A (...and other stuff if I want to join and do things)
```

Comment: Do you need the values of data_value? Otherwise you can group by uid.

Comment: @Aret Yes. I need data_value. Table_A is the consequence of some joins and there are more values than just data_value. I was just trying to simply the problem for S.O

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uid) uid, data_value, modified_at
FROM Table_A
ORDER BY uid, modified_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use a windows function `row_number()` and use cte syntaxis for better reading

```
 WITH cte as (
      SELECT *,
             row_number() over (PARTITION BY uid  ORDER BY modified_at DESC) as rn
      FROM TableA
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM cte
 WHERE rn = 1
```